PowerBI - Get 2 tables from 1 table and subtract them
i have the following data.
Group   Modell  Place COUNT
5         A      T1   1
5         A      T2   1
5         B      T1   1
5         B      T2   2
5         B      T3   2

I want to give the user in PowerBi two different slicers where he can choose the Models he want to compare.
Slicer1 = A
Slicer2 = B

What i now need are the following tables.
Table1
Group   Modell1  Modell2    Place COUNT
5         A         B        T1    0
5         A         B        T2   -1
5         A         B        T3   -2

Table2
Group   Modell1  Modell2    COUNT
5         A         B       -3

Hope someone can help. I tried it with parameters, but i am not able to subtract them.

You can try this

create two tables
Slicer = DISTINCT('Table'[Model])
Slicer2 = DISTINCT('Table'[Model])

create measures
Model1 = SELECTEDVALUE(Slicer[Model])
Model2 = SELECTEDVALUE(Slicer2[Model])
 MEASURE =
 CALCULATE (
     SUM ( 'Table'[COUNT] ),
     'Table'[Model] = SELECTEDVALUE ( Slicer[Model] )
 )
     - CALCULATE (
         SUM ( 'Table'[COUNT] ),
         'Table'[Model] = SELECTEDVALUE ( Slicer2[Model] )
     )





Cool, thanks for your support. It works fine. But do you know if it is possible to work with parameters?

you are welcome. What do you mean by two parameters? select A B for slicer 1 and C D for slicer 2?

You are able to use Modeling - > Parameter in Power BI. It is possible to use in place of filters. Will check it again. But your solution is what i needed  :)
